# Rails can't display image from angular inserted variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I've got a rails app that has Angular on the front end. I have the name for the image file retrieved and inserted using Angular on the front end. However, I just can't get the image to display (but if I were to hard code the link then the image displays). Can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
#this does not display the image, but displays link (i.e. {{officer.id}}.jpg => alice.jpg
<%= image_tag('{{officer.id}}.jpg', :id=>"{{officer.id}}", size: '140x140', :class=>"img-responsive, img-thumbnail", :data=>{:toggle=>"modal", :target=>"##{}{{officer.id}}Modal"}) %>  

#this does work
<%= image_tag('alice.jpg', :id=>"{{officer.id}}", size: '140x140', :class=>"img-responsive, img-thumbnail", :data=>{:toggle=>"modal", :target=>"##{}{{officer.id}}Modal"}) %>
```

officers.coffee.erb (angular code)

```
app = angular.module('officersApp', [])

app.controller 'officerCtrl', [
    '$scope'
    '$http'
    ($scope, $http) ->
        $http.get('./officers.json').success (data) ->                  
            $scope.officersGroup = data.officers
        return
]
```

Comment: Is this in a partial html view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using rails templates, I would use pure angular templates, eg:

```
<img ng-src="{{officer.id}}" id="{{officer.id}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" data-toggle="modal"  />
```

Comment: Thanks to the person who down voted without any explanation almost 1 year after this was posted and accepted.